# The action 'index' could not be found, but it's defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am receiving error `The action 'index' could not be found for AttackNarrativesController` when doing HTTP GET `/attack_narratives`, even though I have the index method defined.

`config/routes.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  resources :attack_narratives
  ...
end
```

`controllers/attack_narratives_controller.rb`:

```rb
class AttackNarrativesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts "test"
  end
end
```

```sh
$ rails routes
...
    attack_narratives GET    /attack_narratives(.:format)            attack_narratives#index
                      POST   /attack_narratives(.:format)            attack_narratives#create
 new_attack_narrative GET    /attack_narratives/new(.:format)        attack_narratives#new
edit_attack_narrative GET    /attack_narratives/:id/edit(.:format)   attack_narratives#edit
     attack_narrative GET    /attack_narratives/:id(.:format)        attack_narratives#show
                      PATCH  /attack_narratives/:id(.:format)        attack_narratives#update
                      PUT    /attack_narratives/:id(.:format)        attack_narratives#update
                      DELETE /attack_narratives/:id(.:format)        attack_narratives#destroy
...
```

The text `test` does not appear in the log.

The view `views/attack_narratives/index.slim` renders just fine, but I need to execute code in the index method to provide certain data to the view.  I'm new to Ruby and Rails, and I've been trying to solve this for hours.  The "magical" nature of Rails is a huge headache for me, because I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting.  I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something simple.  Thanks to all who can help.

```sh
$ rails version
Rails 6.0.2.1
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Interesting, this should work. Try restarting your rails server, perhaps? Spring too, it gets stuck sometimes and doesn't reload code properly.

Comment: what do you mean by "I am receiving error The action 'index' could not be found for AttackNarrativesController" and "The view views/attack_narratives/index.slim renders just fine"? If the view is rendered so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: It seems your problem is not in the parts you are giving us, could you give a link to reproduce it

Comment: `puts` outputs to `STDOUT` so you would see the output in the terminal window where you are running the rails server - but it does not write to the logs. Also is the controller placed in `/app/controllers`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, everyone.  The view works fine, so I disable it to troubleshoot why code in the controller action won’t execute.  I was reviewing stderr for the puts statement.  The line doesn’t execute at all.  I unfortunately cannot provide a codebase because it’s private; however, I can continue to provide snippets.  I’ll give a server restart a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the rails server solved this issue.  Thanks @sergio-tulentsev

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the [Rails Logger](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) in your index action instead:

```
class AttackNarrativesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Rails.logger.info(message: 'test')
  end
end
```

Comment: The action itself can't be found, apparently.